# More efficient method to take picture from Android in-app-cam and upload it to server

Tags: java, android

I'm building an app that require method to take picture from in-app camera, but for some Android devices (old device or low ram), it's quite freeze when taking picture triggered. Is there any code i can modify or optimize to make user experience feels better?

```
//this function trigger to take picture (or screenshot) from user screen
    private void captureImage() {
        mPreview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        final Bitmap[] drawingCache = {Bitmap.createBitmap(mPreview.getDrawingCache())};
        mPreview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

     mCameraSource.takePicture(null, bytes -> {
            int orientation = Exif.getOrientation(bytes);
            Bitmap temp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            Bitmap picture = rotateImage(temp, orientation);
            assert picture != null;
            Bitmap overlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(mGraphicOverlay.getWidth(), mGraphicOverlay.getHeight(), picture.getConfig());
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(overlay);

            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.setScale((float) overlay.getWidth() / (float) picture.getWidth(), (float) overlay.getHeight() / (float) picture.getHeight());

            // mirror by inverting scale and translating
            matrix.preScale(-1, 1);
            matrix.postTranslate(canvas.getWidth(), 0);

            Paint paint = new Paint();
            canvas.drawBitmap(picture, matrix, paint);
            canvas.drawBitmap(drawingCache[0], 0, 0, paint);

//this function to save picture taken and put it on app storage cache
            try {
                String mainpath = getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getPath() + separator + "e-Presensi" + separator;
                File basePath = new File(mainpath);
                if (!basePath.exists())
                    Log.d("CAPTURE_BASE_PATH", basePath.mkdirs() ? "Success" : "Failed");

//this function to get directory path of saved photo
                String path = mainpath + "photo_" + getPhotoTime() + ".jpg";
                String namafotoo = "photo_" + getPhotoTime() + ".jpg";
                filePath = path;

                namafoto = namafotoo;
                SessionManager.createNamaFoto(namafoto);

                File captureFile = new File(path);
                boolean sucess = captureFile.createNewFile();
                if (!captureFile.exists())
                    Log.d("CAPTURE_FILE_PATH", sucess ? "Success" : "Failed");
                FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(captureFile);
                overlay.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP, 60, stream);
                stream.flush();
                stream.close();
                if (!picture.isRecycled()) {
                    picture.recycle();
                }

                if (drawingCache[0] != null && !drawingCache[0].isRecycled()) {
                    drawingCache[0].recycle();
                    drawingCache[0] = null;
                }
                mPreview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
                uploadPicture();
                finish();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `take picture from in-app camera, ` What is an 'in-app camera'?

Comment: `Is there any code i can modify or optimize` Could you first tell what your code does and why those things should happen?

Comment: I meant in-app camera is the camera activity that does not use the camera app from another application that are available installed on the user phone. It doesn't open dialog to open another app. This code is the one that are called when user trigger what is seen on their screen, some kind like screenshot I guess but it took a lot memory to process, I need to optimise it as fast as possible even on user with low memory android. Is there any way to do that? Thanks for your response. @blackapps

Comment: You have not explained what your code does. Nor what it should do and why? Fo we have yo discover that ourselves by looking at the code? No. Tell what should happen and after that we will check the code.

Comment: You still did not tell what your code should do.

Comment: I'm building an app that require method to take picture from in-app camera that use  Manifest.permission.CAMERA to launch camera activity inside application ( not launching other 3rd party camera app ) @blackapps

Comment: This code are already tested and work to take picture from app camera and save it to app cache. But for some device with low RAM available, it's freeze and then the app crash. That's the problem

Comment: You repeated what you want. But you still did not explain your code. And suddenly 'inefficient' becomes  a 'crash'.

Comment: @Shin why don't you try CameraX as its abstracting lots of vendor dependents changes for various phones and provide you a common interface for features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I would advise you to step through your code and look at large memory resources you're generating on each line and consider setting those to null aggressively as you move throughout the method if you're done.

For example, you have a variable called `temp` which is size "Y" bytes that you appear to rotate and then never use `temp` after that. If `picture` is a rotated copy of `temp` then you have now used 2Y bytes of memory to keep `temp` and `picture`. I suspect if you simply set `temp` to null after creating `picture`, you might free up half that memory that your older/slower phones are going to badly need.

Take that same concept and follow through with the rest of your method to see if you can find other optimizations. Basically anywhere you're creating a copy of the image data you're not going to use, you should immediately set it to null so the garbage collector can throw it away aggressively.

Comment: Thank you for your help, i was able to optimize my code by removing all "temp" data when no longer being on use to help reducing the usage of ram while using my app. Sincerely thanks.

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

Firt you need some variables:

```
byte[] byteArray_IMG;
String currentPhotoPath;
static final int REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO = 1;
ImageView imageView; // maybe you need show the photo before send it
```

Then define the method to take the photo:

```
  private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;

        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Error takin the photo",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            path_img = photoFile.toString();
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,"com.app.yournmamepackage.fileprovider" , photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    }
}
```

Create the method to create the file image

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
    currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

Override the activity result to:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

 /*            Bundle extras =  data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap)  extras.get("data");

        imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);

        byteArray_IMG = stream.toByteArray();*/

        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[]{path_img}, null,
                new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                        Log.i("path",""+path);
                    }
                });

        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path_img);
        imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 14, stream);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        byteArray_IMG = stream.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

Remember this is very important

```
imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 25, stream)

 // 25 is photo quality  0-100
```

Then you can upload the picture usin an asynchronous process

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i need a better method or a fix from my code that are already implemented not a new code.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly Initialize these variables above onCreate() method in your activity/fragment

```
val FILE_NAME:String="photo.jpg"     //give any name with.jpg extension
private var imageuri: Uri?=null
val REQUEST_IMAGE=111
```

Now open camera

```
val intent: Intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)

        photofile = getphotofile(FILE_NAME)
        imageuri = activity?.let { it1 -> FileProvider.getUriForFile(it1, "//your package name here//.fileprovider", photofile) }     //put your package name
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageuri)
        startActivityForResult(int, REQUEST_IMAGE)
```

onActivityResult() method

```
if(requestCode==REQUEST_IMAGE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
        val progressdialog: ProgressDialog = ProgressDialog(activity)
        progressdialog.setTitle("Sending Image....")         
        progressdialog.show()                   //start your progressdialog

        val ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
        val messagekey=ref.push().key          //create a key to store image in firebase

        var bmp: Bitmap?=null
        try {
            bmp=MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(activity?.contentResolver,imageuri)   //get image in bitmap
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        val baos= ByteArrayOutputStream()
        bmp!!.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,50,baos)   //compress the quality of image to 50 from 100
        val fileinBytes: ByteArray =baos.toByteArray()

        val store: StorageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("Chat Images/")    //create a child reference in firebase
        val path=store.child("$messagekey.jpg")    //store a message in above reference with the unique key created above with .jpg extension
        val uploadTask: StorageTask<*>
        uploadTask=path.putBytes(fileinBytes)    //it will upload the image to firebase at given path

        uploadTask.continueWithTask(Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>> { task ->
            if (!task.isSuccessful) {
                task.exception?.let {
                    throw it
                }
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Upload Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            return@Continuation path.downloadUrl
        }).addOnCompleteListener { task->
            if(task.isSuccessful){

                url=task.result.toString()   //get the url of uploaded image
                
                //Do what you want with the url of your image                     

                progressdialog.dismiss()
                Toast.makeText(activity, "Image Uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }.addOnFailureListener { e->
            progressdialog.dismiss()
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Failed " + e.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
        uploadTask.addOnProgressListener { task->
            var progress:Double=(100.0*task.bytesTransferred)/task.totalByteCount
            progressdialog.setMessage("Sending ${progress.toInt()}%")   //this will show the progress in progress bar 0-100%
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but i need a better method or a fix from my code that are already implemented not a new code.